# Given n elements, each with m possibilities, what is the probability of seeing certain elements at least once?

Tags: probability

Say there are m different objects I can pick from, and I have n objects. Each has an equal probability of being any of the m possibilities. Each object is determined independent of the others.

Say two of the possibilities are A and B. What is the probability I see both A and B at least once? How is this extended for more than two elements?

For a concrete example: I'm rolling n m-sided dice. I want to know the probability I see all of the numbers 1 through k at least once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let: $A_i$=see Ai object at least once,

so $A_i'$=not see Ai object at all.
Suppose we have a m-sided dice, which I roll it n times.

An example for 3 objects A1,A2,A3

$P(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3)=1-P((A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3)')=1- P(A_1' \cup A_2' \cup A_3')=1-[P(A_1')+ P(A_2')+P(A_3')-P(A_1'\cap A_2') -P(A_3'\cap A_2') -P(A_1'\cap A_3')+P(A_1'\cap A_2'\cap A_3')]$

where

$P(A_i')=\frac{(m-1)^n}{m^n}$

$P(A_i'\cap A_j')=\frac{(m-2)^n}{m^n}$

$P(A_i'\cap A_j'\cap A_l')=\frac{(m-3)^n}{m^n}$

For 4 objects work the same with the use of \begin{align*}
P(A \cup B \cup C \cup D) & = P(A) + P(B) + P(C) + P(D) - P(A \cap B) - P(A \cap C)\\ & \quad - P(A \cap D)- P(B \cap C) - P(B \cap D) - P(C \cap D)\\ 
                          & \quad + P(A \cap B \cap C) + P(A \cap B \cap D) + P(A \cap C \cap D)\\
& \quad + P(B \cap C \cap D) - P(A \cap B \cap C \cap D)
\end{align*} and for k object the same way

Comment: Are you sure your calculation for $P(A'_i)$ is right? For a fixed $m$, it increases with respect to $n$. So $P(A_i)$ decreases as n increases, which doesn't really make sense, since more dice rolls should increase the chance that you see a certain number.

Comment: Ok, never mind, it seems like you just mixed up how I had defined $n$ and $m$.

Comment: Hello. My example is for a n-sided dice, which I roll it m times.

Comment: I feel like there's still a problem. According to your calculation, if I was rolling two six-sided dice, then my chance of seeing both one and two is $1 - {{(6-2)^2} \over {6^2}} = \frac{5}{9}$, which doesn't seem right, since I have 6 possibilities for the first dice, and 6 for the second, so that's 36 total possibilities. The only rolls that work are $1,2$ and $2,1$. So it seems like the probability should be $\frac{2}{36} = \frac{1}{18}$.

Comment: My chance of seeing both one and two, at least once, if you roll  two six-sided dice is given by $P(A \cap B)=1-P(A' \cup B')=1-P(A')-P(B') +P(A'\cap B')=1-2\cdot \frac{5^2}{6^2}+\frac{4^2}{6^2}$

Comment: Ahh, ok. Could you edit your question to clarify what n and m are, so I can accept it?

Comment: Ok I edited it for a m-sided dice, which I roll it n times